# Replicating this design in Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to replicate this design using Python.

I am using the `Graphics` module, [obtained here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hasinqrs2xflsr/graphic.py). I can't use any other Graphic Module at the moment.

This code here allows me to draw 5 circles in a line repeated by a loop.

```
def fdShape():
    win = GraphWin(199,199)
    centre = Point(20,100)
    for y in range(5):
        for x in range(5):
            centre = Point(x * 40 + 20, y * 40 + 60)
            circle = Circle(centre, 20)
            circle.setOutline("red")
            circle.draw(win)
```

One problem that I've found with this code is that it leaves a blank line at the top of the window and place the last circle line at the bottom, beyond the borders of the window. Thats the first problem.

The second is using the code to display semi circles displayed in red. As you can see in the image at the top of this page. I'm unsure of how to replicate this picture using Python.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty close:

[image: screenshot of program's output]

```
from graphic import *

def main():
    repeat = 5
    diameter = 40
    radius = diameter // 2
    offset = radius // 2

    win = GraphWin("Graphic Design", diameter*repeat + offset, diameter*repeat)
    win.setBackground('white')

    for i in range(repeat):
        for j in range(repeat):
            draw_symbol(win, i % 2,
                        Point(i*diameter + offset, j*diameter), radius, 'red')

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def draw_symbol(win, kind, lower_left, radius, colour):
    centre = Point(lower_left.x+radius, lower_left.y+radius)
    circle = Circle(centre, radius)
    circle.setOutline('')
    circle.setFill(colour)
    circle.draw(win)

    if kind == 0:
        rectangle = Rectangle(lower_left,
                             Point(lower_left.x+radius, lower_left.y+radius*2))
    else:
        rectangle = Rectangle(lower_left,
                             Point(lower_left.x+radius*2, lower_left.y+radius))
    rectangle.setOutline('white')
    rectangle.setFill('white')
    rectangle.draw(win)

    circle = Circle(centre, radius)
    circle.setWidth(1)
    circle.setOutline(colour)
    circle.setFill('')
    circle.draw(win)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see.

GraphWin should be initialized to 200x200, not 199x199.

This line:

```
centre = Point(x * 40 + 20, y * 40 + 60)
```

Should most likely be:

```
centre = Point(x * 40 + 20, y * 40 + 20)
```

Comment: This also helped me to gain that extra line of circles. Thank you!